# Android Kotlin - Firestore image upload and display

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

At the moment as a sample I'm recreating instagram-like post, where user can post a description and image (along with username since I'm still not configuring authentication). So far as follows I can only post username and description. Along side of that I can load new image as a source into the imageview on the screen.

My data class is:

```
data class Post(val username: String,
                val timestamp: Date,
                val postTxt: String,
                val numLikes: Int,
                val numComments: Int,
                val documentId: String)
```

I put data in a hashmap as follows:

```
val data = hashMapOf(
                NUM_LIKES to 0,
                NUM_COMMENTS to 0,
                POST_TXT to addPostTxt.text.toString().trim(),
                TIMESTAMP to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                USERNAME to addUsernameTxt.text.toString().trim()
        )
```

and then pass it to upload to firestore:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(POST_REF)
                .add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener { finish() }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.e("Exception", "Could not add post: $it")
                    toast("Could not add post")
                }
```

And to get the data I created a function which takes snapshot of type QuerySnapshot like so:

```
// Clear all the posts before relaod
        posts.clear()

        snapshot.documents.forEach { document ->
            val data = document.data
            val name = data?.get(USERNAME) as String
            val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as Date
            val postTxt = data[POST_TXT] as String
            val numLikes = data[NUM_LIKES] as Long
            val numComments = data[NUM_COMMENTS] as Long
            val documentId = document.id

            val newPost = Post(name, timestamp, postTxt, numLikes.toInt(), numComments.toInt(), documentId)

            posts.add(newPost)
        }

        postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

So far uploading text, current time of upload works fine for both upload and reading it from the database; however my question here is: 
- What is the best way (following current codebase) to upload image to firestore and storage and display it accordingly in the main window (preferably using Glide or picasso)?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to store binary data like images in Firestore.  You could very easily exceed the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) for how much data you can store in a document, which is 1MB.  Large documents also take more time to load on the client, which is even worse if you don't even need to use the image at the time of the read.

Instead, consider uploading the image to Cloud Storage and saving a path to that location in a field in your document.  Then, when it's time to display the image, load it from there.

Comment: Would you by any chance be able to provide such example as a reference since I have little to none experience in uploading files to cloud storage and then displaying them via link to them? In any case thank you.

Comment: The documentation for Cloud Storage for Firebase should be a good place to start. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/